# binding a DataGridView to a DataBase

Tags: datagridview, ado.net

Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1
    Dim cn As SqlConnection
    Dim ds As DataSet
    Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim eleveBindingSource As BindingSource
    Dim builder As SqlCommandBuilder

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    cn = New SqlConnection("Data source=.; initial catalog=tp4_ado; integrated security=sspi")
    ds = New DataSet()
    eleveBindingSource = New BindingSource
    adapter = New SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Eleve", cn)
    adapter.Fill(ds, "Eleve")
    eleveBindingSource.DataSource = ds
    eleveBindingSource.DataMember = "Eleve"
    DataGridView1.DataSource = eleveBindingSource
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    adapter.Update(ds.Tables("Eleve"))
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: What have you tried? If we see what you've tried, we can tell you why it doesn't work or if there's a better way.

Comment: @TimSchmelter okey, I have modified my post

Comment: Alright, I solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't Initialized `UpdateCommand` when I made modification to the `DataGridView`

So I Must add this code before updating the `DataSet` :

```
builder = New SqlCommandBuilder(adapter)
```